# Exactly Counting the Number of Lattice Points in an $n$-Dimensional Sphere

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, computer-science

Let $S_n(R)$ denote the number of lattice points in an $n$-dimensional "sphere" with radius $R$. For clarification, I am interested in lattice points found both strictly inside the sphere, and on its surface. I want to count **exactly** how many such points there are. This count corresponds to the amount of sets of integers that are solutions to the equation $$a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+...+a_{n-1}^2+a_n^2= R^2$$ where the $a_i$'s are required to be integers, not necessarily positive, and sets that differ just by the order of the summands are also considered **distinct**, i.e for the case $n=3, R=5$, the following are both counted: $3^2+(-4)^2+0^2$ and $(-4)^2+0^2+3^2$. This can also be interpreted as the **sum of squares function** - $r_d(k)$ denotes in how many such ways I can write $k$ as the sum of $d$ squares. This means that $$S_n(R) = \sum_{k=1}^{R^2}r_n(k)$$

I am asking this question as a general one, but I am mostly concerned about the cases of $n=2, n=3,n=4$.

In order not to be too lengthy and remain focused, I won't explain why but summing this way requires to factor each $k$ first. This is very time consuming, so I searched for better ways.

For the case of $n=2$, which is essentially just the count of lattice points in a circle of radius $R$, there is a lot of information - this is known as the **Gauss Circle Problem** and I have managed to find that $$S_2(R)= 1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\biggl(\biggl \lfloor\frac{R^2}{4i+1}\biggl \rfloor-\biggl \lfloor\frac{R^2}{4i+3}\biggl \rfloor\biggl )$$For the case of $n=4$, I found: $$S_4(R)= 1+8\sum_{k=1}^{R^2}\sum_{d|k \atop {4\nmid d}}d$$ Unfortunately, for the case of a sphere ($n=3$), I have found no formula, neither for the count of lattice points inside nor on the surface of the sphere.

Although these formulas do indeed provide the count of lattice points, they are very slow in computational terms, as their running time complexity is $O(R^2)$. I was wondering if a more efficient way exists to count the number of such lattice points, perhaps $O(R)$ or $O(R^{1/2+\epsilon})$, so that I can work with radii as big as $10^9$ or even more. I suspect there is a way, but I can't find it. Not necessarily a different approach to the problem, but rather just a more clever way to reduce the order of the sum. Also, any insight about $S_3(R)$ will be appreciated.

Comment: So it is fairly trivial to do an $O(R^{n-1})$ bound by the most naive methods (trivial counting by slicing), which looks as though it might do better in the 2-dimensional case, and give the same bound as you have already seen in 3D.

Comment: Look at Section 4.4 of the book by Iwaniec--Kowalski. The integrals it contains can probably be computed to enough accuracy to give you an exact count.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it @HenriCohen

Comment: By the way: it’s considered bad form to simultaneously (or nearly simultaneously) post the same question on MO and MSE. if you’re not sure, post on MSE first, and if you don’t get an answer after a few days, consider posting on MO (with cross-references to avoid duplication of work).

Comment: And the least you can do when you post to more than one site is to fess up, and leave links. Here's the m.se post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3229538/counting-the-number-of-lattice-points-in-an-n-dimensional-sphere

Comment: Ok, sorry. I didn't know @AnthonyQuas

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson

Comment: I added the word "exact" to the title to distinguish this question from a number of other similar-sounding questions that already exist on MO.

Comment: Yeah, this is important. Thank you! @TimothyChow

Comment: For $S_4(\mathbb R)$ the number of $k$ from $1$ to $R^2$ a multiple of $d$ is $\lfloor \frac{R^2}{ d} \rfloor$ so the sum is $1 + 8 \sum_{d=1}^{R^2} 1_{4 \not | d} d \lfloor \frac{R^2}{d} \rfloor $. Another way to sum this is letting $t = k/d$ and so we get $1+ 8 \sum_{t=1}^{R^2} \sum_{ d \leq R^2/t, 4 \not | d} d $ and there is an explicit formula for $ \sum_{ d \leq R^2/t, 4 \not | d} d $. We should be able to use the first sum for $d \leq R$ and the second one for $d>R$, or the first one for $t > R$ and the second sum for $t\leq R$, to get an $O(R^{1+ \epsilon})$ algorithm.

Comment: A relevant paper is https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0008068.pdf.