# Number of triangles and number of traingles with integer sides in a sphere

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

consider a sphere centered at origin and radius $m \in \mathbb{N}.$ Let $S$ be the set of all points in or on the sphere.Is it possible to find the number of traingles  with vertices in $S?$What about  the number of traingles  with vertices in $S$ and integer side lengths?I posed this problem to myself but I have no idea where to start?What about a the generilisation of the problem in $n-$dimensional space?I would be highly obliged and relieved if somebody could provide any hints/suggestions or any links if the problem has already been considered in the literature .

Comment: The earlier MO question, [Exactly Counting the Number of Lattice Points in an -Dimensional Sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/q/331815/6094), addresses some parts of your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integral triangles in a hypersphere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430412/integral-triangles-in-a-hypersphere)